# Problems with UI UX design for grid elements

Tags: gui-design, design-patterns, layout

i am facing a problem with my grid elements, the design is made to look good when the grid element is filled with long information, but it looks empty and filled with lots of white space when there is less info, what design guidelines and UI i can follow to make these elements look good in both cases.

[image: grid elements]

Comment: Does the space need to be that wide? Does the "Visit" link at the right side need to be so narrow? Couldn't that be a button or just wider?

Answer (score 0):

The white background increases the feeling of emptiness.

If there is no fill content and the layout cannot be modified, a very simple and immediate resource is to add a background to simulate a pseudo content, be it a watermark, a texture, a color, or a gradient:

[image]

In this way, instead of giving importance to the void, the continuity of the background maximizes the perception of the containing frame, the total shape of the card.

Answer (score 0):

Your cards doesn't need to be so wide and you could make the images bigger.

Also the length of your text lines is too big: https://baymard.com/blog/line-length-readability